# How to setup gpp-compiler

Tags: c++

**So for some background:**

> I'm switching languages and I use the atom text editor, Not the ideal
> choice but I'm too lazy to install a different text editor, Ok so I
> tried using the build package, No dice and now I'm switching to the gpp compiler

---

So, First thing is: the instructions are clear as mud, no idea on what to do, Secondly: I don't know what adding to my path means and I even tried googling this, But I don't even know a shred of information on how to setup this cursed beast

- questions:

  *1. can someone guide me through the process of setting up gpp compiler?*

Comment: check this https://atom.io/packages/gpp-compiler  looking for `setting up gpp compiler in Atom` will give you a ton of toturials

Comment: There is a direct option to install the gpp-compiler package within the atom GUI.

Comment: @magmine thanks man, but I didn't find anything of use, still appreciative of you answering though :D

Comment: @AbinThomas can you describe how to do this?

Comment: Open settings tab within atom `Ctrl+,` i guess. And then search for the gpp-compiler package in the install section.

Comment: I done the installation, but I have no clue what to do next

Comment: @submari I guess what you lack is some understanding of what the PATH variable is used for, you should take a look into that. Understanding that will help you install other software in the future.

Comment: @magmine might look into that, thanks mate :D

Comment: @magmine I looked into it, tried everything I've got, still no dice, now there is this error:
"'g++' could not be spawned. Is it installed and on your path? If so please open an issue on the package spawning the process." any clue what this means?

Comment: @submari if you open the terminal and type `g++ --version` do you get any results? if you don't get any then you should follow [these steps](https://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/) where you should add the path of the g++ binary (C:\MingW\...\g++) in the environment variable PATH instead of `C:\Android\platform-tools`  as in the example (so you should know where you installed your compiler)

Comment: aight, I'll try this out, mate

Comment: alright, got that done, but still can't get gpp compiler to work

Comment: it still is the same o'l error